# Understanding behaviour of order by in a query

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

I aim to select full name of employees that either have no boss or their boss lives on a street that contains letter 'o' or letter 'u'. Then, I want to list them in descending order by full name.
The problem comes in the ordering, because by queries that I think are the same I get different answers.

When I introduce in MySQL Workbench the following command:

```
select concat(surnames,', ',name) as 'Full Name', street
from employee
where boss is null or (boss is not null and (street like'%u%' or steet like '%o%'))
order by concat(surnames,', ',name) desc;
```

By this command I get the answer I want, that is:

```
Full Name              Street
Suárez García, Juan Juan Valdés 25
Sarasola Goñi, Vanesa   Austria
Requena Santos, Pilar   Alicante 3
Puertas Elorza, Marta   Lope de Vega 3
Piedra Trujillo, Ramón  Madre Vedruna 21
Narváez Alonso, Alba    Vara de Rey 22
Gómez de la Sierra, Francisco   Loscertales 9
Chávarri Díez, Lorea    
Arrieta Alcorta, Kepa   Urbieta 33
Álvarez González, Ana   Graus 19
```

But when I change the ordering by another that looks the same to me:

```
select concat(surnames,', ',name) as 'Full Name', street
from employee
where boss is null or (boss is not null and (street like'%u%' or steet like '%o%'))
order by 'FullName' desc;
```

I get a wrong answer that looks like:

```
Full Name               Street
Suárez García, Juan Juan Valdés 25
Puertas Elorza, Marta   Lope de Vega 3
Chávarri Díez, Lorea    
Narváez Alonso, Alba    Vara de Rey 22
Gómez de la Sierra, Francisco   Loscertales 9
Piedra Trujillo, Ramón  Madre Vedruna 21
Sarasola Goñi, Vanesa   Austria
Requena Santos, Pilar   Alicante 3
Álvarez González, Ana   Graus 19
Arrieta Alcorta, Kepa   Urbieta 33
```

Can somebody tell me what's going on here?

Comment: it's important when you ask questions here that you copy and paste your actual code/query.  too often typos derail getting answers.

Comment: feedback, not related to your problem: `boss is null or (boss is not null and street...` `or` short circuits; if it is evaluating the right side of the or, boss is guaranteed to not be null, so it can just be `boss is null or (street...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define an alias, you can use either single-quotes, as if it's a string literal, or you can use back-ticks, as if it's an identifier. But when you refer to the alias later in the query, you must treat it as an identifier.

```
order by 'FullName' desc;
```

This orders by the constant string value `'FullName'`, not the alias. Ordering by a constant value or expression makes every row tied with every other row, and the resulting order is undefined.

If you want to refer to the *identifier*, use back-ticks:

```
order by `FullName` desc;
```

By using the identifier, the order is by the *values* of the named column from each respective row, and that will give you the order you want.

This page in the manual talks about this difference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html